# Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") in R trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror Calls: install.packages -> contrib.url Execution halted

Tags: r, package

I have some R code that executes perfectly in RStudio, but when I run it in cmd I get the below error .

```
Installing package into 'C:/Users/Anish/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") :
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted
```

I am including my package in my code as `install.packages("plyr")`. I have also tried using repos and source inside `install.package` function.

Comment: Same error for me. I am already pointing the `repos` to a location in intranet. the package is not  in CRAN. What does this error mean? How do I get more info on the cause of the error?

Answer (score 24):

Use

```
install.packages('plyr', repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Please, explain why & how your code works so that the question and answer can be valuable to less experienced developers

Comment: The first parameter `plyr` is simply just the package to be installed. The repos parameter with a value of `http://cran.us.r-project.org` refers to the preferred [**Mirror** server for CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) during the download.

Answer (score 11):

The reason is most likely because RStudio configures R so it knows how to to check for system packages and where to download them if not locally available, whereas from the command line your R is likely missing that configuration. Check with `R.home(component = "home")` from the command line. In the returned folder look for a file like `Rprofile`. In my system the line was commented (sight):

```
$ grep -i "options(repos" /usr/lib64/R/library/base/R/Rprofile
# options(repos = c(CRAN="@CRAN@"))
```

I experienced the same error re-running an R markdown document on a computer different from the one I had originally written it. To fix it I explicitly set the `repos` option in the first R chuck of the document and then `knitr` started to work instead of getting stuck in this error. The error means that your R session is attempting a package installation using the [contrib.url](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/contrib.url.html) package but the R-language options do not tell it where to get packages from.

Here is the line I introduced in the first R chunk of the Rmd document. I got the idea from [https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/issues/23](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/issues/23#issue-85173672).

```
options(repos = list(CRAN="http://cran.rstudio.com/"))
```

This would give you a closer behaviour from the command line as from the RStudio environment in terms of package downloads anyway.

I suggest setting the option at the top of the script you are running. Of course, the best practice is to configure the R language to your expectations and share that configuration with your audience-users via the R.profile file, read [how to customize R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/09/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/).

Comment: This really solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 7):

i haved same error but i have fixed it with this video information:

[https://youtu.be/SX41BbfKZxA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX41BbfKZxA) Big thanks to Solutions Cloud

In simple words:

Initially i had this:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library("ggplot2")
install.packages("palmerpenguins")
```

And i change it by

```
install.packages("ggplot2", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library("ggplot2")
install.packages("palmerpenguins", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library("palmerpenguins")
```

And Voila, i got it!!!!

and now i'm freaking happy bros

Comment: Points for the passion it communicates. I think this answer is along the lines of the answer by Anjani. It has more examples of explicitly telling R where to get the package from. In this way, it may help less experienced developers because it shows a pattern. However, it does not explain why the less complicated call works in Rstudio while you have to do this extra work at the command line.