# Cleaning data in PowerBI using R

Tags: r, dplyr, powerbi

Let's say I bring in a MS-Excel data into a PBI report. Now I want to clean the data, for starters, I would like to drop the `columns` with all `null` values.

The sample data (SampleData) consists of the following columns:

```
a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
c = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

df = SampleData
```

1. How can I first read this `dataset` as a `dataframe` in `R script Editor`? I have noticed that using `df = Sample Data` and pressing `Ctrl+Enter` doesn't return anything, like I can't see the `df` being loaded in the environment as in `RStudio`
2. If I use `library(tidyverse)` and press `Ctrl+Enter`, will the editor load the package?
3. How can I then use `dplyr` to run the following and then also overwrite `SampleData` with this new cleaned data?

   `df %>%  select(where(function(x) any(!is.na(x))))`

Please note that this is my 1st time using `R` in `Power BI`.

Update:

Thanks to `Nicolás Velasquez` giving me a good start. And I am now stuck at the next step. Right now I am in `Edit Query > transform tab > Run R Script` and tried running the following code

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>%  select(where(function(x) any(!is.na(x))))
```

This is how the code looks like in PBI console

```
= R.Execute("# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script#(lf)library(tidyverse)#(lf)# First replace NULL with NA#(lf)#dataset = dataset %>% replace(.==""NULL"", NA) #(lf)# Remove the columns with NA#(lf)dataset = dataset %>%  select(where(function(x) any(!is.na(x))))",[dataset=#"Changed Type1"])
```

But I get any empty dataset in return which I don't understand as the code is supposed to remove only columns with all `NAs/NULLS`.

[image]

Do I first need to convert the NULLS to NA? (Replacing `NULL` with `NA` doesn't work either)

Update 2:

As `Nicolás Velasquez` PBI Desktop only supports `R 3.4.4` which I have now installed and linked its path in PBI. But now I am getting an error while installing `tidyverse` how can I fix it?

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

Error:

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: R script error.
Installing package into 'C:/Users/Ed_Gravy/Library/3.4.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted

Details:
    DataSourceKind=R
    DataSourcePath=R
    Message=R script error.
Installing package into 'C:/Users/Ed_Gravy/Library/3.4.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted

    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.Exceptions.RScriptRuntimeException
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can only use the R scripts to either load content into de PBI data model, add columns to existing tables (i.e. crate calculated columns), or create visualizations.
If I understand you correctly, you want to do the second. 
Q1. Make sure to select the table in PBI that you want to clean, and then go to the transform tab, and then select R Script.
Q2. You have to install it first. Preferably from outside PBI. Make sure to do it from an MRO 3 3.4.4 (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-r-packages-support)
Q3. Note that PBI converts NA into Nulls.

Comment: @NicolásVelasquez, thank you for the quick response, yes I already have `R` installed, and right now I am in `Edit Query > transform tab > Run R Script`. How can I first load the `tidyverse` package  so that I can use `dplyr`. Should I just use `library(dplyr)` and press `Ctlr+Enter`?

Comment: You have to install it first. (I.e. `install.packages("tidyverse")`). PowerBI does not install R packages by default, and it also is bound to a specific version of R (currently 3.4.4), and specific versions of packages (from around the time R 3.4.4 was released).
You might try to 1. install both MRO R 3.4.4 first, then 2. install from MRO R the package (i.e. outside PBI), then 3. test your script outside PBI, then 4. run it on PBI.
If Step 4 does not work, try adding the `install.packages("tidyverse")` line into PBI's R script.

Comment: I already have `tidyverse` installed that I use in `RStudio` so do I need to install it again for PBI? I do see PBI pick my `R installation` as `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1`

Comment: Well, try it with that R 4.2.1 Install. In the past (~2021) it did not work for me.
In my experience, only 1 out of 10 times you need to include the install.packages line into the PBI code. It is kind of rare but not unseen bug if you need to do it.

Comment: You are right, PBI still only supports `R 3.4.4` which I have now installed. But now I am getting an error while installing `tidyverse`. I am gonna update my question to show the error.

Comment: Did you try to install tidyverse outside PBI and then loading it from PBI? (I.e. Installing it from R 3.4.4's console or Rstudio using R 3.4.4 prior to loading it from PBI)

Comment: No sorry I tried installing it inside PBI

Comment: If everything inside PBI fails, you could try this R package and update PBI's Data Model from R.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/powerbiR

Comment: @Ed_Gravy do the solutions in here help with the most recent error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244209/error-in-contrib-urlrepos-source-in-r-trying-to-use-cran-without-setting-a